# How to reset an NPC's dialogue options to reset a quest in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I got married a few months back to an inn keeper, Wilhelm, but wanted to re-marry someone different. So, like any adventurer, I killed him. Unfortunately, (a) his body is still in my house, on the floor and won't leave and (b) I can't seem to re-marry. I went back to the temple of Mara in Riften and talked to Maromal, but the dialogue that triggers the quest, (Love is in the Air, or something like that.) that allows you to be married, won't come back. I have an amulet of Mara, but no one has given me the interaction to pursue marriage. How do I either reset the quest so I can re-do it, or reset Maromal's dialogue so I can *get* the quest? Also, how can I get rid of Wilhelm's body?
Thanks :)